# Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'credentialResponse.profileObj' as it is undefined

Tags: runtime-error, google-oauth, vite

`

```
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';
import { GoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';
import { FcGoogle } from "react-icons/fc";
import bgVideo from "../../assets/share.mp4";
import logo from "../../assets/favicon.png";
import {client} from "../client/client";


const Login = () => {

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-start items-center flex-col h-screen">
      <div className="relative w-full h-full">
        <video src={bgVideo}
          type="video/mp4"
          loop
          controls={false}
          muted
          autoPlay
          className='w-full h-full object-cover' />

        <div className="absolute flex flex-col justify-center items-center top-0 right-0 left-0 bottom-0 bg-blackOverlay">
          <div className="p-5">
            <img src={logo} width="130px" alt="logo" />
          </div>
          <div className="shadow-2xl">
            <GoogleOAuthProvider
              clientId={import.meta.env.VITE_GOOGLE_API_TOKEN}
              render={(renderProps) => (
                <button
                  type='button'
                  className='bg-mainColor flex justify-center items-center p-3 rounded-lg'
                  onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                  disabled={renderProps.disabled}>
                  <FcGoogle className='mr-4' />
                </button>
              )}
              cookiePolicy="single_host_origin"
            >
              <GoogleLogin
                onSuccess={credentialResponse => {
                  localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(credentialResponse.profileObj))

                  const {name, googleId,  imageUrl} = credentialResponse.profileObj

                  const doc={
                    _id: googleId,
                    _type: "user",
                    userName: name,
                    image: imageUrl
                  }
                  
                  client.createIfNotExists(doc)
                  .then(()=>{
                    navigate("/", {replace:true})
                  })

                }}
                onError={() => {
                  console.log('Login Failed');
                }}
              />;
            </GoogleOAuthProvider>
            {/* Start from 50:15  */}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

`

This is my code please tell me what's wrong with it. And if there is anything wrong with placement of syntax please help me with correct code.

I am trying to create google login but "Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'credentialResponse.profileObj' as it is undefined." error is showing in the console

Comment: Can you see what properties are in the `credentialResponse.profileObj`? Are you able to debug the code and look at the object? I don't see where you are setting the `scope` that should be included with your access token. I would expect that you would need `profile` to be included to retrieve the name. It could be returned as firstName and lastName rather than name.